# Can't restore /data (non-gsi)

Tags: backup, twrp, lineageos, restore, redmi

Redmi 7A (Pine). Some LineageOS ROM was working for years, but I decided to update Magisk via the app, that was a big mistake...

The system failed to boot so I backed up only `/data` without `/data/media` via TWRP. Flashed LineageOS 17.1, and it loads fine, flashing again but restoring `/data backup`. It fails to load, only a loading logo for several minutes and it goes to recovery'

Tried LineageOS 18.1 (https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-arm64-unofficial-lineageos-18-1-for-redmi-7a-pine.4267861/), the same. Hope somebody will help me restore my data :`\ Backup` is called 2023-07-05--12-45-26_RQ3A210605005_test-keys and has structure of four archives and some info: data.ext4.win000, win001, win002, win003, and sha2 for each archive, data.info and recovery.log

Answer (score 0):

I outplayed the problem. TWRP makes a backup of the "Nandroid" type, using Titanium Backup Pro (used v8.3.1.2) restored the application with data, copied the TWRP folder (in which BACKUPS) to internal storage (example /sdcard/TWRP/BACKUPS/...) , because it does not see the SD card (written in additional F.A.Q. - https://4pda.to/forum/index.php?showtopic=152562&st=28820#entry57719632):

> "Question: I can not restore data from a nandroid backup. Writes
> backup not found. What should I do?      Answer: On some firmwares
> with Android 6 and higher, this behavior is available, or in TWRP the
> path to the backup has been changed, which Titnium cannot see. The
> solution is here В® Titanium Backup (Post vasilyevaa # 69824786) Or
> use third-party utilities to work with nandroid backups."

If after restoring the application + data the application does not start, then use SD Maid Pro (used v5.5.10 b50510) to completely delete the application, install the latest version or the same version, but from the full APK and restore only the data, it helped me. Do not delete the backup in any case (it will always come in handy) and do not unpack (the chmod and chown attributes and some other attributes will disappear in Windows)